# Run apt from a sysroot directory

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, apt

I have a sysroot in my ubuntu 18.04 located at ~/sysroot. I have a debian based system there and the packages in the sysroot are compatible with the host architecture. Now, how can I run apt from the sysroot to install a package, e.g: apt-get install randompack, so that randompack is obtainable from sources included in the sysroot's sources list: ~/sysroot/etc/apt/sources.list. Also how can I tell apt to use the ~/sysroot as its root directory, so that it can look for dependencies and install missing ones for a package from the sysroot directory.

Further, in case of cross compilation, when libraries in sysroot are meant for a different architecture, can I still run apt to install packages in the sysroot.